# Compare two arrays in react and filter one based on matches of name property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state, recoiljs

I'm trying to filter a players array by comparing the names property to a roster array and rendering the matches from the players array.

When a user selects a year the getCollegeRoster() function returns players who have a year property matching the selection. From there I'm trying to filter and display the .name matches from the players array, but it seems i'm unable to update playerStateValue. I'm using recoil to manage state. Any insight would be much appreciated.

````
const getCollegeRoster = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const playersQuery = query(
        collection(firestore, `colleges/${communityData.id}/rosters`),
        where("year", "==", selection),
      );
      const playerDocs = await getDocs(playersQuery);
      const collegeRoster = playerDocs.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
      setRoster(collegeRoster as unknown as Roster[]);
      console.log('collegePlayers', roster);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("getCollegePlayers error", error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };


const onSelection = (newSelection: any) => {
    setSelection(newSelection);
    console.log('newselect', newSelection)
    getCollegeRoster();
    const filteredArray = [...playerStateValue.players].filter((el) => ({
      name: el.name,
      match: [...roster].some((f) => f.name === el.name)
      })
    );
      setPlayerStateValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        players: filteredArray as Player[],
        playersCache: {
          ...prev.playersCache,
          [communityData?.id!]: filteredArray as Player[],
        },
        playerUpdateRequired: false,
      }));
   } ```  


also tried adding setplayerstatevalue into the getcollegeroster function:


onst getCollegeRoster = async () => {
    console.log("WE ARE GETTING Players!!!");
    console.log('communitydata', communityData);

    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const playersQuery = query(
        collection(firestore, `colleges/${communityData.id}/rosters`),
        where("year", "==", selection),
      );
      const playerDocs = await getDocs(playersQuery);
      const collegeRoster = playerDocs.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
      setRoster(collegeRoster as unknown as Roster[]);
      console.log('collegePlayers', roster);
      const filteredArray = [...playerStateValue.players].filter((el) => ({
        name: el.name,
        match: [...roster].some((f) => f.name === el.name)
        })
      );
        setPlayerStateValue((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          players: filteredArray as Player[],
          playersCache: {
            ...prev.playersCache,
            [communityData?.id!]: filteredArray as Player[],
          },
          playerUpdateRequired: false,
        }));
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("getCollegePlayers error", error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };




{playerStateValue.players.map((player: Player, index) => (
            <PlayerItem
              key={player.id}
              player={player}
              // postIdx={index}
              onPlayerVote={onPlayerVote}
              userVoteValue={
                playerStateValue.playerVotes.find((item) => item.playerId === player.id)
                  ?.voteValue
              }
              onSelectPlayer={onSelectPlayer}
            />
````

Comment: `getCollegeRoster()` does not return anything?

Comment: I updated my code here to show the getCollegeRoster() - it does return the roster array correctly

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. `getCollegeRoster()` is an `async` function which means it is being executed asynchronous.
That function is responsible for updating `roster` and you are using `roster` inside your filtering while it is being asynchronously updated.

There is no guarantee that `roster` is updated by the time you filter your array.

You have two ways of solving this. Either you execute `setPlayerStateValue()` inside of `getCollegeRoster()` or you wait for `getCollegeRoster()` to be done by preappending it with `await` and your `onSelection` function with `async`:

```
  const onSelection = async (newSelection: any) => {
    setSelection(newSelection);
    console.log("newselect", newSelection);
    await getCollegeRoster();
    const filteredArray = [...playerStateValue.players].filter((el) => ({
      name: el.name,
      match: [...roster].some((f) => f.name === el.name),
    }));
    ...
```

**Edit:**

Another scenario I can think of is that `playerStateValue` might be the culprit. In React `setState` works asynchronous as well, if you access `playerStateValue` via `curr/prev`-callback, it is guaranteed that you are accessing the values of the current state object while updating the state. Try this use of `setPlayerStateValue`:

```
    setPlayerStateValue((prev) => {
      const filteredArray = prev.players.filter((el) => ({
        name: el.name,
        match: [...roster].some((f) => f.name === el.name),
      })) as Player[];

      return {
        ...prev,
        players: filteredArray,
        playersCache: {
          ...prev.playersCache,
          [communityData?.id!]: filteredArray,
        },
        playerUpdateRequired: false,
      };
    });
```

Comment: good call on async but still not getting updated playerstatevalue with either fix

Comment: Did you console.log roster? Is it the expected value?

Comment: yup roster updates correctly based on selection

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try it out?

Comment: yea same thing. I added to the bottom of my code where im rendering the final array in the return in case something might be off there